# Show list date foreach person data in MySQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have table named absen_calendar and absen, absen_calendar only contain list of dates from 2018-11-01 until 2018-11-30.

```
absen_calendar
| dateCalendar |
|  2018-11-01  |
|  ...         |
|  2018-11-30  |
```

and another table named "absen".

```
absen
personName | personDate | personTime | personInfo
Joko       | 2018-11-01 | 07:26:00   | IN
Eko        | 2018-11-20 | 07:03:00   | IN
Wahyu      | 2018-11-15 | 17:11:00   | OUT
Joko       | 2018-11-01 | 17:40:00   | OUT
```

I'm trying to show list date in dateCalendar for each personName in absen's table. Sometimes 1 person could be only have 1 personInfo in personDate.

```
result
dateCalendar | personName | personTimeIN | personTimeOUT
2018-11-01   | Joko       | 07:26:00     | 17:40:00
2018-11-02   | Joko       | NULL         | NULL
...
2018-11-30   | Joko       | NULL         | NULL
2018-11-01   | Eko        | NULL         | NULL
...
2018-11-30   | Eko        | NULL         | NULL
2018-11-01   | Wahyu      | NULL         | NULL
...
2018-11-15   | Wahyu      | NULL         | 17:11:00
...
2018-11-30   | Wahyu      | NULL         | NULL
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
  d.dateCalendar,
  a_in.personName,
  a_in.personTime AS personTimeIN,
  a_out.personTime AS personTimeOUT,
FROM absen_calendar d
LEFT JOIN absen a_in
ON a_in.personDate = d.dateCalendar
AND a_in.personInfo = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN absen a_out
ON a_out.personDate = d.dateCalendar
AND a_out.personInfo = 'OUT'
```

How to do this in MySQL or PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a table that lists all the person names?

Comment: No, i only have 2 tables, absen and absen_calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

use `CROSS JOIN` with `absen_calendar` table make a full table for name and calendar, then  `absen` table `OUTER JOIN` base on the result set.

then use `CASE WHEN` with `MAX` do pivot.

```
SELECT ac.dateCalendar,
       name.personName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN personInfo ='IN' THEN personTime end) personTimeIN ,
       MAX(CASE WHEN personInfo ='OUT' THEN personTime end) personTimeOUT
FROM absen_calendar as ac 
cross join (select distinct personName from absen) name
LEFT JOIN absen a on a.personDate =ac.dateCalendar and a.personName = name.personName
GROUP BY 
  ac.dateCalendar,
  name.personName
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d3c5a/1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with the table that lists all person names. If you don't have such a table for real, you can get the list of names from `absen` (but this means if someone has never been in or out, you have no way of finding their name -- this is very poor database design).

```
SELECT d.dateCalendar, p.personName, a_in.personTime AS personTimeIN, a_out.personTime AS personTimeOUT
FROM absen_calendar AS d
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT personName
    FROM absen) AS p
LEFT JOIN absen AS a_in
ON a_in.personDate = d.dateCalendar
AND a_in.personName = p.personName
AND a_in.personInfo = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN absen AS a_out
ON a_out.personDate = d.dateCalendar
AND a_out.personName = p.personName
AND a_out.personInfo = 'OUT'
```